# scrapy item loader to get a absolute url from extracted url

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using/learning `scrapy`, python framework to scrape few of my interested web pages. In that go I extract the links in a page. But those links are relative in most of the case. I used `urljoin_rfc` which is present in `scrapy.utils.url` to get the absolute path. It worked fine.

In a process of learning I came across a feature called `Item Loader`. Now I want to do the same using Item loader. My `urljoin_rfc()` is in a user defined function function `_urljoin(url,response)`. I want my loader to refer the function `_urljoin` now. So in my loader class I do `link_in = _urljoin()`. So I canged my _urljoin declaration to `_urljoin(url, response = loader_context.response)`. 
But I get a error saying `NameError: name 'loader_context' is not defined`

I need help here. I do this because, not just while loading I call _urljoin(), other part of my code too call the function _urljoin. If i am terribly doing bad please bring it to my notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `_urljoin(url, response)` elsewhere, you can keep as it is, accepting a response as 2nd argument.

Now, processors for `Item Loaders` can accept a context, but the context *is a dict of arbitrary key/values which is shared among all input and output processors* ([from the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#item-loader-context)).

So you could have wrapping function calling your `_urljoin(url, response)`:

```
def urljoin_w_context(url, loader_context):
    response = loader_context.get('response')
    return _urljoin(url, response)
```

and in your `ItemLoader` definition:

```
    ...
    link_in = MapCompose(urljoin_w_context)
    ...
```

and finally in your callback code, when you instantiate your `ItemLoader`, pass the response reference:

```
def parse_something(self, response):
    ...
    loader = ItemLoader(item, response=response)
    ...
```

Comment: That means I cant have a loader function and a general function in common. and I dont do much in _urljoin. So I will do my work in a two different(loader function and general function) function which will save my switching period. Thank you

Comment: And where should this code `link_in = urljoin_w_context` be? I was writing this code in my spider inside a class abcLoader(ItemLoader)

Comment: hey I would be glad if you could tell where and how should I call Loader function @paul t.

Comment: I edited my answer to use the processor in ItemLoader. Other ways to use input/output processors are detailed in [the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#input-and-output-processors)

Comment: I am finding bit confused here. Not getting a write way to add loaders. Can you tell me where and how should I declare and define ItemLoader. by where I ment in which file. Is it in spider or in Items. Should I use Mapcompose(). cant I directly call a function name

Comment: You can define you `ItemLoader` subclass anywhere, in items.py for example, or in your spider file. From what I understand that's already where you define your `class abcLoader(ItemLoader)`, you can keep it there, and referencing your `_urljoin_w_context` processor there

Comment: A typo in your solution it should b ' return response.urljoin(url)'