# Python Scrapy get absolute url using input processor

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to create an input processor to convert scraped relative urls to absolute urls, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970015/scrapy-item-loader-to-get-a-absolute-url-from-extracted-url) Stackoverflow post. I'm struggling with the loader_context concept and I'm probably mixing things up here. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

I have the following in items.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose
from urlparse import urljoin

def convert_to_baseurl(url, loader_context):
    response = loader_context.get('response')
    return urljoin(url, response)


class Item(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=MapCompose(convert_to_baseurl)
    )
```

And the following in my spider

```
class webscraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        for entry in response.css('li.aanbodEntry'):
            loader = ItemLoader(item=Huis(), selector=entry)
            loader.add_css('url', 'a')

            yield loader.load_item()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `_urljoin()` in the answer you referenced is a function written by the OP, and it has a different signature than the one in the stdlib.
The correct way to use the stdlib [`urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) would be:

```
return urljoin(response.url, url)
```

There is no need to use that however, since you can use [Response.urljoin()](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.urljoin) :

```
def absolute_url(url, loader_context):
    return loader_context['response'].urljoin(url)
```

For the response to be accessible through the `context` attribute, you need to pass it as an argument when creating the item loader, or use a different method mentioned in [item loader docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#item-loader-context):

```
loader = ItemLoader(item=Huis(), selector=entry, response=response)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Great to find out that Scrapy has this built in. However, I tried using response.urljoin() as you suggested but I get a "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'urljoin''.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you need to pass the response as an argument to the item loader for it to be accessible through `context`. Will update my answer to mention this.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much!